# Android: Add LinearLayout first at ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want add new item to top at listview

After run, application force closed

> Code :

```
final ArrayList<StructNote> notesPage = new ArrayList<StructNote>();
final ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);
adapter = new AdapterNote(notesPage);
View addNew = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.addnew, null);
adapter.insert(addNew, 0);
lstContent.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> Error log :

```
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.app.network.StructNote
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at com.app.network.AdapterNote.getView(AdapterNote.java:612)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1611)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-01 15:39:02.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
```

StructNote save item each listview

> StructNote :

```
public class StructNote {
    public int     id;
    public String  singer;
    public String  title;
}
```

AdapterNote set into listview foreach child of listview

> AdapterNote :

```
public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

    public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.post, array);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ...
}
```

Comment: What is `StructNode` and `AdapterNote`?

Comment: @JamesWierzba , I update my question

Comment: adapter.insert(addNew, 0); You should add a StructNote ,not a View.

Comment: Exactly , How convert LinearLayout to StructNote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final ArrayList<StructNote> notesPage = new ArrayList<StructNote>();
final ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);
adapter = new AdapterNote(notesPage);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View addNew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addnew, lstContent, false);
lstContent.addHeaderView(addNew, null, false);
lstContent.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```